# PuTTY Windows 7 jump lists won't work

Tags: windows-7, putty

One of the newer features of [PuTTY 0.61](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is the support of Windows 7 jump lists to start saved sessions. When this version of PuTTY came out I was on a "loaned" computer and it worked great!

Now I have my actual computer and a clean install of Windows 7, the jump lists feature does not work. When I right click on the PuTTY icon in the taskbar I just see the unpin and launch options.

Is there something that is not setup correctly or something that I've somehow forgotten?

Comment: This probably belongs on puTTY's bug tracker.

Comment: Could you try creating a shortcut to putty anywhere in your start menu and see if it works afterwards?

Comment: @billc.cn That is what I have done, no luck.

Answer (score 6):

1. Right-click on the Start menu
2. Select Properties
3. On the "Start Menu" tab, in the Privacy section, enable "Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar"

This should do the trick.

Comment: TY TY TY! I couldn't figure out why they weren't appearing! SOLVED

Comment: I had the same problem with Putty.  I unpinned it from the menu bar opened it and then re-pinned it and the jump-lists started working.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to open the saved session(s), and after that, the connections will apear in jump list.

That's how is working fro me.

Comment: That is what I have done. But the jump list shows nothing other than the standard items.

Comment: I was asked to restart computer after install putty from installer. Are using putty standalone or from installed?

Comment: I am using the standalone putty.exe and that is what I was using on my previous computer too. But I'll give the installer a try and report back.

Comment: Well, with the installer version of putty I get "Run Pageant" and "Run Puttygen" in my jumplist. But I'm still not seeing my saved sessions.

Comment: Worked well for me.